# Can not find `/var/run/docker.sock` in docker container after `docker run -id -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock {xxx} /usr/sbin/init`

Tags: docker

I want to use docker command in a docker container, to build docker images. So I found a solution from [here](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/). I followed the instruction and I succeeded to build docker images in running container.
I start the container as follows:

```
docker run --privileged=true -id -host -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock {image_name}`
```

And then I can use `docker exec -it {container_id} /bin/bash` to get into the container and run `docker build` in the container.

But if I start the container as follows:

```
docker run --privileged=true -id -host -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock {image_name} /usr/sbin/init
```

I can not use docker command in the container any more.
Here, I use `/usr/sbin/init` to start `ssh` server int the container. I check the container and I find that `/var/run/docker.sock` is not found in the container. This is why the docker command in the container can not work.

But I don't know why `/var/run/docker.sock` is not found in the container with `/usr/sbin/init` and how I can solve it.

Anybody help? Thank you.

Comment: Can you correct the `docker run` command (neither `-id` nor `--host` is a valid option; I've seen some similar questions where option ordering causes a problem)?  If you need an interactive login, privileged access to the system, and the host's Docker socket, why not just use `sudo` and save a layer of Docker?

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry for my typing error, where `--host` should be `-host`. I don't get your idea of 'use sudo and save a layer of Docker'. I use the docker container as a develop environment, where I will compile my code and generate docker images. So, I just treat the docker container as a server, which I can login by `ssh`.

Comment: Anybody help me?

Comment: @GOGO Did you ever find a solution to this problem? Im struggling with the same